# Reading from CSV file and "save" it's contents to List objects and load them in Program.cs

Tags: c#, list, constructor, console-application, csvhelper

My goal with my small Console Application is to read from a CSV file and save it's contents inside a List (which works). I have a separate class with this method. See the uncommented section in UserList.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using CsvHelper;

namespace GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI
{
    public class UserList
    {
        // public static List<User> DefaultUsers()
        // {
        //     // First line to skip a row and position all users correctly under the right headers
        //     User user0 = new User("", "", "", "");
        //     // Create user default instances
        //     User user1 = new User("Beheer", "beheer@gimpies.nl", "123", "admin");
        //     User user2 = new User("Inkoop", "inkoop@gimpies.nl", "123", "purchase");
        //     User user3 = new User("Verkoop", "verkoop@gimpies.nl", "123", "sales");
        //     // List of users (with a list you can add, get and remove items in the list)
        //     List<User> users = new List<User>();
        //     users.Add(user0);
        //     users.Add(user1);
        //     users.Add(user2);
        //     users.Add(user3);

        //     // Return all the users in the List to other classes
        //     return users;
        // }

        public void LoadUsersFromCSV(List<User> users)
        {
            // using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
            // using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("users.csv"))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                try
                {
                    csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                    csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                    csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                    csvReader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => header.ToLower();
                    csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                    csvReader.Read();
                    csvReader.ReadHeader();
                    
                    // Store all content inside a new List as objetcs
                    var usersfromcsv = csvReader.GetRecords<User>().ToList();  
                    

                    // return users;
                                  
                }
                catch (CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

In my Program.cs I want to call this method and use the contents of that created List to use the login code. So to check if the username and password are typed correctly and users can log in.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using CsvHelper;

namespace GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // List of default users
            // List<User> users = UserList.DefaultUsers();
            
            // Working on it... Try to read csv file first and try to read list from method in UserList.cs
            // UserList ul = new UserList();
            List<User> users = UserList.LoadUsersFromCSV();
            // List<User> users = 
            // ul.LoadUsersFromCSV(users);
        

            // Create login instance
            LoginManager loginMgr = new LoginManager();

            // Create stock instance
            Stock stock = new Stock();

            Start:
            // Welcome message
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Gimpies Console Application! Choose 1 to login or 2 to exit this application:");

            // Get input from user
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            // Set to false to check if login fails or not
            bool successfull = false;

            while (!successfull)
            {
                if(input == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
                    string username = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter your password:");
                    string password = Console.ReadLine();

                    foreach (User user in users)
                    {
                        if (username == user.username && password == user.password && user.userrole == "admin")
                            {
                                // Create Admin instance to be able to call methods in that class
                                Admin am = new Admin();
                                // Calling the method in Admin.cs to start Menu logic
                                am.AdminLoggedIn(users); 
                                
                                successfull = true;
                                break; 
                            }

                        if (username == user.username && password == user.password && user.userrole == "purchase")
                            {
                                // Create Purchase instance to be able to call methods in that class
                                Purchase pc = new Purchase();
                                // Calling the method in Purchase.cs to start Menu logic
                                pc.PurchaseLoggedIn(users);
                                
                                successfull = true;
                                break; 
                            }
                        
                        if (username == user.username && password == user.password && user.userrole == "sales")
                            {
                                // Create Sales instance to be able to call methods in that class
                                Sales sl = new Sales();
                                // Calling the method in Sales.cs to start Menu logic
                                sl.SalesLoggedIn(users);
                                
                                successfull = true;
                                break; 
                            }
                    }

                        if (!successfull)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Your username or password is incorrect, try again !!!");
                            }
                }

                else if (input == "2")
                {          
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                }

                else if (input == "3")
                {
                    FileOperations fo = new FileOperations();
                    // Calling the method from FileOperations.cs to write the List here to a CSV file
                    fo.WriteUsersToCSV(users);
                    goto Start;
                }

                else if (input == "4")
                {
                    FileOperations fo = new FileOperations();
                    // Calling the method from FileOperations.cs to write the List here to a CSV file
                    fo.ReadUsersFromCSV(users);
                    goto Start;
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try again !!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            // // Loop over stored users within instances inside the list where users are added
            // foreach (User user in users)
            // {
            
            //     if(loginMgr.Login(user))
            //     {
            //         // Login successfull
            //         Console.WriteLine("Login user " + user.UserName);

            //     }
            //     else
            //     {
            //         // Not successfull

            //     }
            // }  
            
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Program.cs(20,41): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'users' of 'UserList.LoadUsersFromCSV(List<User>)' [/home/pascalmariany/Projects/Csharp/GimpiesConsoleOOcsvList/GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI/GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI.csproj]
```

This is my User.cs with it's constructor:

```
namespace GimpiesConsoleOOcsvListUI
{
    public class User
    {
        // Constructor
        public User(string username, string email, string password, string userrole)
        {
            _UserName = username;
            _Email = email;
            _Password = password;
            _UserRole = userrole;
        }

        private string _UserName;
        private string _Email;
        private string _Password;
        private string _UserRole;

        public string username
        {
            get { return _UserName; }
            set { _UserName = value; }
        }

        public string email
        {
            get { return _Email; }
            set { _Email = value; }
        }

        public string password
        {
            get { return _Password; }
            set { _Password = value; }
        }

        public string userrole
        {
            get { return _UserRole; }
            set { _UserRole = value; }
        }
        
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to reach my goal?

Comment: Do not use `goto`

Comment: I know :-) I still need to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youve declared your LoadUsersFromCsv method as "takes a list":

```
public void LoadUsersFromCSV(List<User> users)
```

but you're trying to use it like "takes nothing and returns a list"

```
List<User> users = UserList.LoadUsersFromCSV();
```

The compiler is complaining because you didn't supply a List in the "users" parameter

---

Looking at the code, it reads the file in and turns it into a list but doesn't return it and it doesn't fill the list it was given either..

I'd suggest you change the LoadUsers method so it returns the list it reads, change it from void to `List<User>` and remove the users parameter

Comment: I changed my method. It's not the full code due to limited characters here in comments:

`
 public static List<User> LoadUsersFromCSV()
{
// Store all content inside a new List as objetcs
                    var users = csvReader.GetRecords<User>().ToList();  
                    
                    foreach(var user in users)
                    {
                        users.Add(user);
                    }
                    return users;
}
`

And from Program.cs:

`
 List<User> users = UserList.LoadUsersFromCSV();
`

The error: "not all code paths return a value"

Comment: Maybe handy. The code is on GitLab: https://gitlab.com/marianydesign/gimpiesconsoleoocsvlist

Comment: Not all code paths return a value means C# has determined there is some way to exit a method without returning a value. All ways out of a method must return a value if the method is declared as returning a value. For example `public string GetDriverLicenseNumber() { if(age < 15) return "Too young to have a license"; }` - this doesn't return anything if the age is greater than 14, which is a compiler error. I don't really know what your code now looks like but I assume "similar to the question" (hint: you can edit your question with minor changes)

Comment: As a result it means there *is* a route out of the method without returning any value: suppose any line of code inside the `try`, before the `return users` were to crash, the C# would start executing the `catch`, but then after that, there isn't any `return` statement. The *only* way to get to the existin `return users` is for everything to work out, and C# knows *that might not happen if something crashes*

Comment: OK, I took a look at the github code, and it has a couple of problems; your csv reader already returned you a list, but you then put a foreach and tried to add every user in the list *to the list again* - this won't work a) because you cannot modify a list while you're enumerating it and b) it isn't what you wanted to do anyway. Just return the users you got when you called ToList(), delete the `foreach` entirely (your question code is more correct; uncomment the return). You also have that problem i mention above; if C# ever executes the catch, it will never hit a return statement

Comment: Thanks. For now I removed the try catch block. Than it works. I have a different problem now, but I'll post a new question. It's about writing the list to the csv file when I log in as admin. It deletes the first entry in the csv file, but adds the new registered users at the end of the users.csv file. Lol! :-)